# Xcode; Perform segue programmatically, for iOS 7

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I'm developing an iOS app with Xcode and Swift.

I'm actually using this code for switching to another ViewController:

```
let vc : AnyObject! = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("FirstView")
if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {
    self.showViewController(vc as! UIViewController, sender: vc)
} else {
    // Fallback on earlier versions
}
```

This is only for iOS 8 and newer. But my app should support iOS 7, too.

Does anybody know what to do in order to support iOS 7?

Comment: `performSegueWithIdentifier("segueID", sender: nil)`

Comment: you want to push the `ViewController` or present the model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually use **presentViewController**, just change StoryboardID of ViewController and call this function

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    let VC1 = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("FirstView")
    self.presentViewController(VC1, animated:true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. But: Why does it work even if don't use `UINavigationController`?

Comment: if you do not have navController you can use self.presentViewController(VC1, animated:true, completion: nil). I suppose it works because navController was instantiated in the method